# How can I implement passport.js Twitter strategy for Restful Api?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, passport.js, restful-authentication, passport-twitter

I am making a simple restful API with Node.js and MongoDB. I want to use Twitter Strategy of Passport.js. There are tons of example for web apps. Routes are redirected to an HTML page. I don't want this. How can I solve my situation?

Comment: Hi FK7, you said that you don't want to be redirected to an html page. You want to stay on the same page? Please clarify!

Answer (score 1):

You can check my [tutorial](https://medium.com/@robince885/how-to-do-twitter-authentication-with-react-and-restful-api-e525f30c62bb) here. I have explained the whole workflow.

You should use [passport-twitter-token](https://github.com/drudge/passport-twitter-token) library. Passport-twitter is not the most suitable one for REST API. This was the biggest issue when I have been working on authentication with Twitter for REST API.

Comment: Every single explanation or tutorial on the web uses request which is now deprecated. How can we use that without request.
All i need is something to transform my APP Secret into an oauth_signature. Crazy!